# Singleton or Utility Class?

Tags: ios, enums, typedef

I have an iOS app that uses a number of enums for valid values, mostly as I’m using some integer-driven state transition tables, but also allows lower memory usage and the ability to index-search in SQLite, which I am using for the backend.

I’ve got all the enums in a common .h file, which is included across a number of classes that create variables based on the enum type. I also have several methods which are used across many classes. Some of them  are translating the enums back to strings, with the typedef and a (human) language as paramaters.

One of the typedefs is below:

```
typedef enum {
    Ben,
    Sen,
    O,
    Biz,
    Siz,
    Onlar
} pronoun_typedef;
```

There are also another set of methods, mostly string manipulation which are fed several parameters and return a `NSString*` or `NSMutableString*`.

I’ve already moved these around to different classes a few times, and I am thinking the best approach might be to create a “utility” class and include it in each relevant class, and instantiate as required.

Is this a good approach? The other option I considered would be to create a singleton, and then forward reference it to every class where it would be required. Any suggestions on which approach to use, or any suggestions for other approaches?

I know this is a similar question to this and some others but I didn't feel it was conclusively answered so I thought I ask again. [Singleton and Static Utility classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582881/singleton-and-static-utility-classes)

Comment: On the link you provided, the answer from roberttdev was more precise.

Comment: He says: _Static Utility is used when you have a class that is just stateless utility functions.. it does not maintain state. An instance of the object is never instantiated._ How can you reference the methods if there is no instantiated object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the utility methods don't need a reference to self, I would make them C functions defined in the same module as the constants. You need an .h file with the constant definitions and function declarations (prototypes), and a .c file with function bodies defined.

If it needs to be an object, use a singleton if single instance makes sense, and multiple instances if each one needs a private, independent copy of its internal data/state.

Comment: C functions. Interesting, I hadn't considered that angle. It will make sense for some of them. Others have some objects involved. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You can manipulate objective-C objects inside a C function as ling as the headers defining said objects are imported. I'm not sure if the file containing the C function body must be .m or it can be .c. If you want to manipulate NSStrings, you will need Foundation at least.

Comment: In any case, keep it simple. Don't define a class if all you need is functions. The less clutter, the more simplicity, the less headaches down the road!

Comment: Really that's quite interesting about manipulating the ObjC objects within the C function. The objects would mostly be NSString or NSMutableStrings anyway.

Comment: I believe Xcode will treat .c files as plain-old-C, disallowing Objective-C syntax (bracket messages). I never tried an .h/.m file pair without @interface/@implementation (i.e., only C functions/variables). Must check if OK

Comment: I used .h/.m for C style functions declarations and implementations code.  No need to use @interface/@implementation statements.