# Is this a good use of a Singleton?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I'm a new programmer, trying to get down some best practices.  I'm writing a simple class with one method.  It takes a long and returns an int (representing an amount of memory) depending on how big that long is.

I'm going to want more than one of these memory models, and it seems like each one should be a separate Singleton.  Is that a reasonable use of the Singleton pattern?  I don't *need* only one instance ever to exist, but it seems like this kind of class is conceptually a Singleton.  Is that a good reason to make it a Singleton?  Or would it make sense to add a private constructor and make the method static?  Or am I overthinking the whole thing?  The code is something like this:

```
public class MemoryModel implements SomeInterface {

   public int get(Long links) {

      final int result;

      if (links < 700_000) {
          result = 50_000;
      } else {
          result = 140_000;
      }

      return result;
   }
}
```

EDIT: If I understand everyone's answers correctly, the answer is no.  I don't want exactly one instance of this class -- there's no reason to ever instantiate it at all.  I should just make the method static and never have to instantiate.

I also get the sense from the answers and links that the Singleton Pattern is overused and can be problematic because it creates a global entity.  Singletons should be used only when there's a good reason to require the existence of only one instance.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/

Comment: Why does it take a `Long` instead of a `long`? You don't test for `null` which means you'll get a NullPointerException on the line of the `if` statement if `links` is null.

Comment: In the actual code I do test for null.  I just took out all the non-essential code so the idea would be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it static...

First the class you have there is not in anway a singleton.  A singleton is a class that guarantees you will only create one instance of it.

Second, there's no reason (yet) mentioned why you would need an instance.  You would want an instance to preseve an object's state.  The object you have there has no state (no fields = no state), only a method -- hence it can be made static.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes total sense.

Answer (score 4):

Singleton classes are use when you might want to reference the same class at multiple places without creating a new object of that class.

In the example you gave it looks like it should be in a public static method as it doesn't have any thing to do with the instance of the class.

There is a difference between singletons and utility classes please read on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582881/singleton-and-static-utility-classes).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I wasn't familiar with the "static utility class" lingo.  Useful idea, I'll implement it that way since I have no reason to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a singleton pattern which you have here. You just have a method in a class.

Probably you can read here first, then try implementing a singleton again:

[Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: I know it's not a singleton as is.  I was wondering whether this was an appropriate situation in which to use the pattern.  I'm convinced now that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you need only 1 instance of something does not mean that you should make it a singleton. If you can avoid it, don't do it.

Your goal is to call `new MemoryModel()` only once. Your problem is that you need a way to reference that object from different places.

But the best option for doing that is to simply pass a reference to that object around. This solves the problem with singletons: the global `static` reference they provide.

```
static final Object singleton = new Object();
static void doStuffBad() {
    // bad.. hardcoded reference & also global state
    System.out.println(singleton);
}

static void doStuffGood(Object reference) {
    // good, this does not create any bad dependencies etc.
    System.out.println(reference);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doStuffBad();
    doStuffGood(new Object());
}
```

---

There are cases in which passing references around gets stupid. So some singletons like `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` (a `Comparator`) make sense. It might in fact make sense in your case too. It really depends on what you're trying to achieve and why you want to make something a singleton. You should not if you want one because you need to access objects at different places and your object hierarchy is so messed up that passing references is too painful.

Answer (score 1):

It's a static function clearly.

Singleton it's a creational pattern. Not only has an unique instance, it also encapsulate the creation algorithm.

It's not make sense to use singleton, if you use singleton you duplicate memory use, you have a static method, and a static variable pointing to a instances on heap. But with static method you only have a static method nothing on heap (and using less heap in java is better).